# restricting filelist from xml file failing

Tags: python, xml, loops, file-io

**This still won't run as is, but hopefully it will give a little more info**
I have this bit of code:

```
#import modules
import os, sys, datetime, time
# sys.setdefaultencoding is cancelled by site.py
reload(sys)    # to re-enable sys.setdefaultencoding()
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
processed = 0
    #here if sync_list.xml doesn't exist, I ask for some user input i want to save between sessions
    #then I save that info to sync_list.xml, along with the element to store files already synced
    root = ET.Element("root")

    synced = ET.SubElement(root, "synced")
    synced.set("name", "Already Synced")
    sfile = ET.SubElement(synced, "sfile")
    sfile.set("date", today)
    sfile.text = "firstsync"

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write("sync_list.xml")
#If sync_list.xml already exists, then I grab the info
tree = ET.parse("sync_list.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
#I pull in all the info I need to work with and:
for elem in root.findall('sfile'):
    synced = elem.text
dcheck = 0
for elem in root.findall('synced/sfile'):
  fdate = elem.attrib.get('date')
  if fdate == today:
    dcheck += 1
synced = [elt.text for elt in root.findall('synced/sfile')]
#if sync_list.xml exists get the list of (UUIDs) $entries that have already been synced, and exclude them from the current query. If no UUID's exist in sync_list.xml, ignore
synclimit = 10 - dcheck
print "Already synced today: " + str(dcheck)
print "Today's synclimit: " + str(synclimit)
if synclimit == 0:
    print "Sorry, you've reached your limit for file syncing today. The limit is reset each night at 12:00 a.m."
    sys.exit()
synclimit = int(raw_input("How many files do you want to sync today? You have a max amount of " + str(synclimit) + " left today: "))

for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    if processed >= synclimit:
        print "You've successfully synced " + str(synclimit) + " files."
        sys.exit()
    else:
        if filename.endswith('.txt') and filename not in synced:
            filename = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
            #process the files. This is where I'm getting variable dofilename
            #The processing works correctly. It's just going over the same files that have already been synced

            tree = ET.parse('sync_list.xml')
            synced = tree.find('synced')
            sfile = ET.SubElement(synced, "sfile", date=today)
            sfile.text = dofilename

            tree.write('sync_list.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
            processed += 1

            print 'Synced ' + dofilename + '....>'

print 'done!'
```

and what it is meant to do is check sync_list for a file name, and not process those files.

**Expected Output:**
If I had a directory:

```
/root
  |_ file1.txt
  |_ file2.txt
  |_ file3.txt
  |_ file4.txt
  |_ file5.txt
  |_ file6.txt
  |_ file7.txt
```

and I ran the script on day1 with a synclimit of 5, I would expect the xml output to look like:

```
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file1.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file2.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file3.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file4.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file5.txt</sfile>
```

This works as expected, but if I were to run it on the second day with a sync limit of 10, I would get:

```
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file1.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file2.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file3.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file4.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file5.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/27/2012">file1.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/27/2012">file2.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/27/2012">file3.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/27/2012">file4.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/27/2012">file5.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/27/2012">file6.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/27/2012">file7.txt</sfile>
```

What I was hoping for, would be, no matter what the synclimit was set to, that the script would skip those files that have already been processed, and instead give me output like this:

```
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file1.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file2.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file3.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file4.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/26/2012">file5.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/27/2012">file6.txt</sfile>
<sfile date="11/27/2012">file7.txt</sfile>
```

Grateful for any guidance, as to where I'm going astray.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code, but there is not enough of it to be able to run it.  Can you post an example which runs (including input data and expected output) and shows the problem.  That will make it easier for us to test it.

Comment: make a simple file(such as `done_list.csv`) and store a list of processed files in it against that day; and then use this file in start of your program to verify on second(future date) day;(for example: you can verify that any files of on date `26` that was processed are not going to process this time(on `27`th).. and after each processing update that information in that file.. .simple.. .

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing with `if filename.endswith('.txt') and filename not in synced:` I'm checking the sync_list.xml to make sure the entry isn't already synced, and if it is, I was hoping it would skip it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple problem, I just wasn't seeing it. I was redefining `synced` when writing the new entry to sync_list.xml.

```
synced = ET.SubElement(root, "synced")
```

Changing this to a different variable fixed everthing. Thank you.